# Why I'm getting nil after pasing input date field with NSDateFormatter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have the following piece of code:

```
messageDictionary["date"] = dataArray[3] as! String
print(messageDictionary["date"])
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let sent_date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(messageDictionary["date"] as! String)

print("SENT DATE IS \(sent_date)")
```

The output from it is:

```
Optional(2016-28-04T18:05:34.978UTC)
SENT DATE IS nil
```

Why in the second line I'm getting `nil` since the format is the same as input string?

Comment: Unless there was 16 more months added when I wasn't looking, you have your MM and dd swapped in your date format.

Comment: @dan that was it, eh, always those small details... If you bother enough feel free to submit an answer and I will mark it as the correct one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dateFormatter dateFormat is different of the string your trying to create a NSDate from.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Should be:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

However if you using different date formats, I recommend creating an extension for NSDate:

```
extension NSDate {

  enum DateFormats: String {
      case ISO = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
      case YYMMDD = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  }

  convenience init?(dateString: String, format: DateFormats) {
      let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = format.rawValue

      guard let d = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) else { return nil }
      self.init(timeInterval: 0, sinceDate: d)
  }
}
```

With this you now can do:

```
let newDate = NSDate(dateString: "2016-28-04T18:05:34.978UTC", format: .ISO)
```